# eglibc: Getting Uptime in Milliseconds

Tags: linux, logging, gettime, gettimeofday, eglibc

I want to write a log-output with the same format as the kernel-log:

```
[   11.947248] fsl-gianfar ffe24000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up
```

The timestamp should have the same time-reference as the kernel time. This means, when a log-message is emitted at the same time as it is done in the kernel, the timestamps should have the same value.

The `clock_gettime` has a undefined clock starting-point - thus the timestamp of every program has a different value - even if they were created at the same time:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
```

When using `gettimeofday` you get the time since the Unix-epoch... which does not match by definition.

The function `localtime()` returns the uptime - but the granularity is in seconds - but I need more...

---

**Update**: [It seems](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/975563) that `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts)` should do what I want... but **eglibc** seems to return `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` instead.

Comment: Reading /proc/uptime is not a solution for each logging call, and getnstimeofday() is only available in kernelspace...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is first to find the offset for your CLOCK_MONOTONIC.
Just read the `/proc/uptime` once for that.
Then use the offset and CLOCK_MONOTONIC to print the time for every logged event.